# Nvidia-docker add folder to container

Tags: linux, docker, nvidia, digits

I'm pretty new to docker containers. I understand there are ADD and COPY operations so a container can see files. How does one give the container access to a given directory where I can put my datasets?

Let's say I have a /home/username/dataset directory how do I make it at /dataset or something in the docker container so I can reference it?

Is there a way for the container to reference a directory on the main system so you don't have to have duplicate files. Some of these datasets will be quite large and while I can delete the original after copying it over .. that's just annoying if I want to do something outside the docker container with the files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that during the build time. If you want to do it during build time then you need to copy it into the context

Or else when you run the container you need to do a volume bind mount

```
docker run -it -v  /home/username/dataset:/dataset <image>
```

Answer (score 1):

Directories on host can be mapped to directories inside container.

If you are using docker run to start your container, then you can include `-v` flag to include volumes.

```
docker run --rm -v "/home/username/dataset:/dataset" <image_name>
```

If you are using a compose file, you may include [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes) using:

```
volumes:
  - /home/<username>/dataset:/dataset
```

For a detailed description of how to use volumes, you may visit [Use volumes in docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/)